# Builder without input parameters, with a static build method?

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style, builder

I know and often use the classic "Builder" design pattern which is described among others [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). 
However, I have now a case in which I would like to use something like a Builder pattern, but in this particular case I do not have to set any parameters in my "Builder", because all values which are used by the "Builder" are constant and do not have to be set dynamically. 
I implemented my "Builder" now as a classic Builder, like this (the code is simplified):

```
final class MyBuilder {

    private static final String FOO = "foo";
    private static final String BAR = "bar";

    private List<MyResult> results = new ArrayList<>();


    MyBuilder() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    List<MyResult> build() {
        results.add(createFoo());
        results.add(createBar());

        return results;
    }

    private MyResult createFoo() {
        ...
    }    

    private MyResult createBar() {
        ...
    }    

    ...

}
```

This builder is used like this:

```
MyBuilder resultsBuilder = new MyBuilder();
List<MyResult> results = resultsBuilder.build();
```

or can be alternatively used like this:

```
List<MyResult> results = new MyBuilder().build();
```

Due to the fact that unlike a classic Builder this particular "Builder" doesn't expect any input parameters (no setters of the builder have to be invoked), it could provide a static method which will create an instance of it and return the final result, so that the builder could be used like this:

```
List<MyResult> results = MyBuilder.build();
```

The "builder" could contain the following code in such case (the build() method is static):

```
final class MyBuilder {

    private static final String FOO = "foo";
    private static final String BAR = "bar";

    private List<MyResult> results = new ArrayList<>();


    private MyBuilder() {
        // hidden constructor
    }

    static List<MyResult> build() {
        MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder();
        return builder.build();
    }

    private List<MyResult> buildResults() {
        results.add(createFoo());
        results.add(createBar());

        return results;
    }

    private MyResult createFoo() {
        ...
    }    

    private MyResult createBar() {
        ...
    }    

    ...

}
```

Is it still a Builder? Is such a modification of the Builder pattern OK in your opinion? 
Does a different design pattern exist which could be more suitable in this particular case?

I had read about the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), but I came to the conclusion that my case is not a factory method pattern, because it doesn't use polymorphism. See the first sentence of the aforementioned article:

> "In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a
>   creational pattern which uses factory methods to deal with the problem
>   of creating objects **without specifying the exact class of object
>   that will be created**."

I specify the exact class of the objects which will be created by my static method. See also the Definition chapter in the aforementioned article:

> "The factory method pattern should not be confused with the more
>   general notion of factories and factory methods. The factory method
>   pattern is the best-known use of factories and factory methods, but
>   not all uses of factory methods are examples of the factory method
>   pattern – only when inheritance is involved (a class implementing an
>   interface, or derived class, implements a factory method) is it an
>   example of the factory method pattern. More basic uses of factories
>   are not examples of the factory method pattern, and may instead be
>   referred to as the factory pattern or a simple factory; these are
>   discussed at [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29)."

So maybe this is a kind of a simple factory (not to confuse with the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern))? What do you think about it?

How should the class "MyBuilder" (where "My" is a placeholder for a business specific name) be called? Maybe MyFactory?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) I don't think its just a factory method, ie a method for producing a fixed object.

The builder allows you to specify options to the object to be built before it is built, so that the instance built can be varied. A factory method just produces an instance of your object when called and is often static.

You could consider an approach where your builder class a static methods to return a default builder instance which has a lot of the options pre-configured, which you can then further modify. But if you are always wanting to return the same object then your factory method is fine.

Comment: I had read the same Wiki article about the factory method pattern as referenced by you before I wrote my question. I came to the conclusion that my case is not a factory method pattern, because it doesn't use polymorphism. See the first sentence of that article: "In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without specifying the exact class of object that will be created." I specify the exact class of the objects which will be created by my static method. See also the Definition chapter.

Comment: The ["Definition" chapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Definition) of the same Wiki article states: "The factory method pattern should not be confused with the more general notion of factories and factory methods. The factory method pattern is the best-known use of factories and factory methods, but not all uses of factory methods are examples of the factory method pattern – only when inheritance is involved (a class implementing an interface, or derived class, implements a factory method) is it an example of the factory method pattern. ..."

Comment: @krm yeah you are probably right its not a Factory Method in the true definition of the pattern, its just a small 'f' factory method, ie a method for producing an object. either way, I think the main point stands, that your class isn't a builder. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Sam. I started to answer using the comments below your answer, but came to the conclusion that it's too much text and added my thoughts about it to the main question. I also tend to the conclusion that it's some kind of a simple factory. How would you call the class in my case which contains this (and only this) static "factory" method? It's rather not a Builder, but can it be called MyFactory (the part "My" is of course a placeholder for something business specific).

Comment: I added +1 for your answer, but I'm still eager to hear what other people maybe have to say about this.

Comment: @krm : I am curious to know which pattern you used here. It is not builder.. I understand .. and I guess you used the variation of factory and how?